# Finding all records that do NOT join on inner join of two tables?

Tags: sql-server, join, inner-join

I have a SQL Server query for an inner join...

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA 
INNER JOIN tableB on tableA.my_id = tableB.my_id
```

How would I find all the records that did NOT match in this join?

Comment: Which table do you want the records from?

Comment: I would like records from both tables that do not match. (I'm very new to MSSQL).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [FULL JOIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt8wzxy4.aspx) to combine the two tables, then use a WHERE clause to filter the results down to only non-matching rows by checking for a NULL in each tables primary key value.

> **Full outer join** All rows in all joined tables are included, whether they are matched or not.

```
SELECT a.pk, b.pk
FROM tableA a 
FULL JOIN tableB b ON a.pk=b.fk
WHERE
    a.pk IS NULL 
    OR b.pk IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT A2.* FROM TableA A2 
              WHERE A2.my_id NOT IN 
                       (Select tableA.my_id FROM 
                                     tableA 
                                     inner join 
                                     tableB 
                                     on tableA.my_id = tableB.my_id)
```

you could similarly do the above starting `SELECT B2.* FROM TableB B2`, in order to separately query unmatched records in Table B

- if you want all records in one table you could UNION ALL the two queries, depending on the table field structures being the same or how you specify the fields you select - what are you doing with the data?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM tableA where my_id NOT IN (SELECT my_id from tableB)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM tableB where my_id NOT IN (SELECT my_id from tableA)